# Firebase "set" completion callback is not firing

Tags: firebase

I was playing around with Firebase (free plan) and ran into an issue with the completion callback for `set` not being called when the data being set exceeded a certain number of keys. The limit varies depending on how deeply nested your data is but for a 1 deep object, that limit seems to be 1453 keys. Above 1453 and the completion callback never fires.

```
var data = {};

// Change 1453 to 1454 and the completion callback never fires
for (var i = 0; i < 1453; i++) {
    data[i] = true;
}

rootRef.set(data, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue or has a guess as to why it is happening?

EDIT: I am doing this in node

Comment: Just to be clear: the completion callback never fires **and** the value also never ends up in your Firebase?

Comment: The value appears in firebase but the callback never fires

Comment: how do you know it never fires?

Comment: @lombausch I know it doesn't fire because nothing every gets output to my console

Comment: what if your "err" is "" ?

Comment: It's never "". It's "null" if there is no error.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found something?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended.  The callback associated with the .set() method is optional and only will receive an err obj if there was an error.  Since there is presumably no error as the data is being written to firebase then the resulting param of err is actually null and therefore you are not seeing anything in the console.

adjust your console.log to this:

```
rootRef.set(data, function (err) {
    console.log("callback complete! ", err);
});
```

Now if you run your code you will see "callback complete!" in the console and you will only see the 'err' if it actually exists.